# mysql / matlab: optimize query - removing dates from a list

Tags: mysql, matlab

I have a table with ~3M rows. The rows are `date`, `time`, `msec`, and some other columns with int data. Some unknown fraction of these rows are considered 'invalid' based on their existence in a separate table `outages` (based on date ranges).

Currently the query does a select * and then uses a huge WHERE to remove the invalid date ranges ( lots of 'and not ( RecordDate >'2008-08-05' and RecordDate < '2008-08-10' )') and so on. This blows away any chance of using an index.

Im looking for a better way to limit the results. As it stands now the query takes several minutes to run.

Comment: Why the down vote? What did I do wrong?

Comment: not sure but some people insist on seeing code in a question, I guess your particular question left too much ambiguity. Personally I disagree in this instance, so I voted it back to 0.

Comment: Something to grow on. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE b FROM bigtable b
INNER JOIN outages o ON (b.`date` BETWEEN o.datestart AND o.dateend)
WHERE (1=1)  //In some modes MySQL demands a `where` clause or it will not run.
```

Make sure you have an index on all fields involved in the query.

Comment: Thanks. That's a different direction than I was thinking.

Comment: Question: when I use this method on a table with ~2M rows its taking > 10 min to run. Seems excessive. Its indexed by RecordDate ('date') in your example. 'outages' table has 3 rows. Also: this syntax seems to remove everything BUT whats in the 'outages' table - if I wanted the opposite (keep all but 'outages') would I change it to 'not between'?